# xsl call template for specific node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have following xsls:

`<xsl:template name="subsection-command">
       <xsl:if test="@variant and /isip/@requestToChangeFlag">
        <xsl:call-template name="request-to-change" />
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>`

`<!-- Link for request to change -->
    <xsl:template name="request-to-change">
      <xsl:variable name="checked">
          <xsl:if test="@marked">
            <xsl:text>checked="checked"</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="@variant and //@requestToChangeFlag and not(@state) and      not(@lockowner) and //@checkout='true' and not(self::component-procref) and not(//@documenttype='WiringVariant' and name(parent::node())='descop')">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@marked">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="requestToChange_nodeUID_{@uid}__prodSpecUid_{//@uid}__routeToRef_{@REF}"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <input type="checkbox" name="requestToChange_nodeUID_{@uid}__prodSpecUid_{//@uid}__routeToRef_{@REF}"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> <a href="{$servlet}?action=route&amp;prodSpecUid={//@uid}&amp;routeToRef={@REF}">Request to change</a>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>`

I would like to call "request-to-change" template only for 
`<consolidated-training>` node when processing.

Ive tried some approaches with xsl match but doesnt work.

Im newbie in xsl topic.

How can I achieve that ?

Below is the input xml.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<isip MAINTAIN_WIRING_CODES="true" OpenStatus="open" REF="G1001364" author_mdx_objects="true" checkout="true" countrycode="DEU" edit_acp_codes="true" forcetranslate="true" langcode="de" maintain_cpsc_codes="true" maintain_index_items="true" maintain_labor_times="true" manufacturer="" model-name="" model-year="2020" quarter="0" uid="G1001364" userid="rtesh" variantid="2117">
    <system OpenStatus="open" REF="G1001365" moidref="G27" order="sysno" sysno="1" title="Allgemeine Informationen" titleref="T6367" uid="G1001365">
        <group OpenStatus="open" REF="G1001366" grpno="00" moidref="G28" order="grpno" title="Service-Informationen" titleref="T5" uid="G1001366">
            <section OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1001367" moidref="G29" order="sectno" qualref="+Q106077[AAA]" sectno="00" suffix="A" title="Allgemeine Informationen" titleref="T6367" uid="G1001367">
                <qualifier OpenStatus="closed" title="AAAFahrzeuge ausgestattet mit Air Conditioning">
                    <dtcprefix OpenStatus="closed" id="Q106077" title="AAA"/>
                </qualifier>
            </section>
            <section OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1001384" moidref="G29" order="sectno" qualref="+Q106068" sectno="00" suffix="B" title="Allgemeine Informationen" titleref="T6367" uid="G1001384">
                <qualifier OpenStatus="closed" title="GB">
                    <territory-mfc OpenStatus="closed" id="Q106068" title="GB">
                        <mfc OpenStatus="closed" code="waegb" type="C" vl="vla1"/>
                        <mfc OpenStatus="closed" code="waegb" type="T" vl="vltg"/>
                    </territory-mfc>
                </qualifier>
            </section>
            <section OpenStatus="open" REF="G1006070" moidref="G29" order="sectno" sectno="00" suffix="C" title="Allgemeine Informationen" titleref="T6367" uid="G1006070">
                <vscs OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1006071" moidref="G957692" uid="G1006071"/>
                <e-product-intro OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1006073" moidref="G983989" uid="G1006073"/>
                <consolidated-training OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1006075" moidref="G1006065" uid="G1006075"/>
                <descop OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1006077" moidref="G30" uid="G1006077"/>
            </section>
            <section OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1001387" moidref="G957735" order="sectno" qualref="+Q105582+Q105548" sectno="06" title="Vehicle Communications" titleref="T13995" uid="G1001387">
                <qualifier OpenStatus="closed" title="130, Tiertransport">
                    <bodystyle OpenStatus="closed" id="Q105582" title="130"/>
                    <conversiontype OpenStatus="closed" id="Q105548" title="Tiertransport"/>
                </qualifier>
            </section>
        </group>
    </system>
    <system OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1001390" moidref="G58" order="sysno" sysno="2" title="Fahrwerk" titleref="T8826" uid="G1001390"/>
    <system OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1001426" moidref="G841" order="sysno" sysno="3" title="Antriebsstrang" titleref="T5022" uid="G1001426"/>
    <system OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1001431" moidref="G2251" order="sysno" sysno="4" title="Elektrische Systeme" titleref="T5023" uid="G1001431"/>
    <system OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1002210" moidref="G3039" order="sysno" sysno="5" title="Karosserie und Lackierung" titleref="T5024" uid="G1002210"/>
</isip>`

Comment: Well at least show the code of the named template `request-to-change`,. Does it have any parameters? Does it assume a context node? What output do you want to create for the element `<consolidated-training OpenStatus="openable" REF="G1006075" moidref="G1006065" uid="G1006075"/>`? Beginners tend to use `call-template` with named templates instead of `apply-templates` and template matching, we can only help you improve the code if we understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: In general it is complitated I use many other xsls and in summary they are creating body of the JSP (Java server pages). I have to improve the code in order to use the 'request-to-change' template only on this node.I ve added request to change xsl in the topic above.

Comment: You have relative path expressions like `@marked` or `@variant` in the template? Are those supposed to read the attributes from the `consolidated-training` element? Or which element you want to be the context node when the template is used or called?